# Casting the right subclass at runtime

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have the following base and derived classes :

```
public abstract class Drone {
    public void Drone(){}
    public abstract boolean commonFunc();
}

public class DroneMain extends Drone {
    @Override
    public boolean commonFunc(){
        return false;
    }

    public boolean droneMainFunc(){
        return true;
    }
}

public class DroneOther extends Drone {
    @Override
    public boolean commonFunc(){
        return true;
    }

    public boolean droneOtherFunc(){
        return false;
    }
}

public class DroneMgr {
    public enum DroneType {MAIN, OTHER}

    public Drone getDrone(DroneType type){
        if (type.equals(DroneType.MAIN))
            return new DroneMain();
        else
            return new DroneOther();
    }
}
```

The code that calls these classes is as follows:

```
private DroneManager droneManager;
private Drone drone;

droneManager = new DroneManager();
drone = droneManager.getDrone(DroneManager.DroneType.MAIN);
boolean value = drone.droneMainFunc();
```

My Question is regarding the following lines:

```
drone = droneManager.getDrone(DroneManager.DroneType.MAIN);
boolean value = drone.droneMainFunc();
```

How do I make it so that I can call droneMainFunc() from the drone object?

Otherwise, how do I do that if I do not know its type until runtime.
If I cannot use the Drone (drone instance) then I wouldn’t know until runtime, I would have to create both a DroneMain object and a DroneOther object and then only assign/cast one based on the returned type.  I would like to avoid that as I am sure there is a better pattern to this.

Comment: despite that, `public getDrone` needs a return type. Additionally by calling `DroneManager.DroneType.MAIN` you should know that it does return a `DroneMain` and you should simply be able to cast it afterwards.

Comment: @KevinEsche - So that means I have to declare both types and then only instantiate one and leave the other null?

Comment: Added a return value of Drone, thx.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way would be the usage of the `instanceof` operator.

```
drone = droneManager.getDrone(DroneManager.DroneType.MAIN);
if (drone instanceof DroneMain) {
    ((DroneMain)drone).droneMainFunc();
} ...
```

But i´d consider including another abstract method into your `Drone` class which would simply call the correct function. That´s because it seems that you want to execute a function indepent on it´s actually class. If so you should include another common function in the abstract class, which both implentations could use aswell, as your `Drone#commonFunc`.

```
public abstract class Drone {
   public void Drone(){}
   public abstract boolean commonFunc();
   public abstract boolean doSomething();
}

public class DroneMain extends Drone {
   @Override
   public boolean commonFunc(){
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean doSomething() {
       return droneMainFunc();
   }

   public boolean droneMainFunc(){
       return true;
   }
}

public class DroneOther extends Drone {
   @Override
   public boolean commonFunc(){
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean doSomething() {
       return droneOtherFunc();
   }

   public boolean droneOtherFunc(){
       return false;
   }
}

...

boolean value = drone.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got two options for you:

Skip the enums and use classes and generics instead. This allows you to make assertions in *DroneMgr* about type and return the correct one as the correct type.

```
public class DroneMgr {
    public <T extends Drone> T getDrone(Class<T> type) {
        if(DroneMain.class.equals(type)) {
            // Need to cast to T, but we already know that T is DroneMain
            return (T) new DroneMain();
        } else if (DroneOther.class.equals(type)) {
            return (T) new DroneOther();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Drone class " + type);
        }
    }
}
```

To use:

```
DroneMain drone = droneManager.getDrone(DroneMain.class); // No need to cast
boolean value = drone.droneMainFunc();
```

Another option is to use the strategy pattern and implement the functionality directly in the enums, this makes it easy to add new types.

```
public enum DroneType {
    MAIN {
        @Override
        public boolean handle() {
            return new DroneMain().droneMainFunc();
        }
    },
    OTHER {
        @Override
        public boolean handle() {
            return new DroneMain().droneOtherFunc();
        }
    };

    public abstract boolean handle();
}
```

Then you just do:

```
boolean value = DroneType.MAIN.handle();
```

If you're not a fan of writing the implementation in the enums you can break out the functionality to separate classes that all implement a common interface and just have a reference to the instance in the enums.

```
public interface DroneHandler {
    boolean handle();
}

public class DroneMainHandler implements DroneHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean handle() {
        return new DroneMain().droneMainFunc();
    }
}

public class DroneOtherHandler implements DroneHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean handle() {
        return new DroneOther().droneMainFunc();
    }
}

public enum DroneType {
    MAIN(new DroneMainHandler()),
    OTHER(new DroneOtherHandler());

    public final DroneHandler handler;

    private DroneType(final DroneHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }
}
```

Usage then becomes:

```
boolean value = DroneType.MAIN.handler.handle();
```

Comment: Thanks @Raniz. Based on your first solution using generics, it made me change my question somewhat.  It made me realize that I want to be able to keep the drone instance and use that to call a method defined only in DroneMain.  So, exactly how I had it:


'drone = droneManager.getDrone(DroneManager.DroneType.MAIN);
boolean value = drone.droneMainFunc();'